Include table into shaded areas
I have the following code which provides an example with a table explaining it (note that I just put in some filler text in the example). The example is using the shaded* command. Now I was wondering if it is somehow possible to also include the table in the shaded area? I guess, since a table is a floating opject, this will be hard.
This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, tikzmark}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shaded*}
\textbf{Example:} \lipsum[3]
\end{shaded*}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Example.}
    \[
    \begin{array}
    {@{\hspace{1em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}}
        \toprule
        \text{Day} & \text{$d=1$} & \text{$d=2$} & \text{$d=3$} & \text{$d=4$}  \\
        \midrule
        \text{Shift} & \tikzmarknode{A}{\text{Mor}} & \tikzmarknode{B}{\text{Night}} & \text{Night} & \text{Noon} \\
  \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
        \draw[red, thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}


I suggest not using a float environment but a simple center with \captionof{table}{...}.
By the way, array is a math mode evironment, you don't need \text{$...$}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, tikzmark}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shaded*}
\textbf{Example:} \lipsum[3]
\begin{center}
    \captionof{table}{Example.}
    \[
    \begin{array}
    {@{\hspace{1em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}c@{\hspace{1.5em}}}
        \toprule
        \text{Day} & d=1 & d=2 & d=3 & d=4 \\
        \midrule
        \text{Shift} & \tikzmarknode{A}{\text{Mor}} & \tikzmarknode{B}{\text{Night}} & \text{Night} & \text{Noon} \\
  \bottomrule
    \end{array}
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
        \draw[red, thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{shaded*}

\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}


I tried to re-create the example using your template, but I can't reproduce the issue to describe in your comment.
Look at this example and let me know if it helps:
\documentclass[poms,final,nonblindrev]{poms1_V1} 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure, epsfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, tikzmark}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  position=above, aboveskip=-8pt, font={small}, labelfont={bf}, labelsep={quad}
  }

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shaded*}
\textbf{Example:} \lipsum[3]
\begin{center}\def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \captionof{table}{Example.}
    \[
        \begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*5c}
        \hline
        \hline
        Day & $d=1$ & $d=2$ & $d=3$ & $d=4$  \\
        \hline
        Shift & \tikzmarknode{A}{Mor} & \tikzmarknode{B}{Night} & Night & Noon \\
        \hline
        \hline
   \end{tabular*}
    \]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]  
        \draw[red, thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{shaded*}

\lipsum[4-5]

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Numbers and numbers}
\centering
        {\def\arraystretch{1.5}  %change the number for increasing or decreasing the spacing.
            %\scriptsize %uncomment this for changing the font size
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcc}
\hline
\hline
1st number & 2nd number & 3rd number\\
\hline
One        & Two        & Three\\
Four       & Five       & Six\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\label{table:mechanical_property}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Thank you very much. I tried to apply it to my bigger project, sadly it does not work as it does in the MWE. In my case, the whole shaded area is not show but rather in this page, some of the prior text is weirdly spaced (maybe 5x vertical spacing). I don't have any customized \captionsetup and I use the same packages. Any idea which package could yield problems? I use this template: https://www.poms.org/journal/author_instructions

@lukdooxb1 I can't reproduce the issue you describe, see my renewed answer. Please take my second MWE and try to reproduce your problem, adding it into your question, thanks.

Off-topic: subfigure is obsolete package. Please, use subfig or even better subcaption instead of it.

@Zarko subfigure is in the template given by the OP in their comment above.
